# Window.Location does not open new tab in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, navigation, standards, specifications

I have a web page like this (pseudocode):

```
<script>
 function clicked(e) {
   url = (find first a inside e).href;
   window.location.href = url;
 }
</script>
<div onclick="clicked(this)">
 <a href="www.google.com>google</a>
</div>
```

The behavior of this differs in chrome and in other browser. When I click with the **MIDDLE** button on the div I get the following behavior:

- IE, FF and Opera open www.google.com in new tab/window
- Chrome opens google in current window.

**I know how to fix this, but my question is what is the correct behavior following W3C standards?**

- I found somewhere that when script changes the href attribute it should internally call assign method.
- In [this document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-location-assign), there is a statement saying:

  > Navigation for the assign() and replace() methods must be done with
  >   the browsing context of the incumbent script as the source browsing
  >   context.

  If I understand that correctly, It means that at this step JS is still working with the original window
- [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigate) I found description of the browsing context navigations. There does not seem to be explanation for why to open a new tab. Step 2 allows creating new window, but I am not sure that this step applies for my case.

  > In all of these cases, the user agent may additionally offer to open the new resource...

Otherwise there seems to be no reason for the browser to open new tab.

Is there some standard that says what to do in this case or is this a choice of browser authors how to handle it? Is it a bug in Chrome or in FF,IE,Opera? Have I missed something?

Comment: I might not understand the context, but I don't think what you're trying to do is a good idea. You should style your a-tag instead of wrapping it in a div that must also be clickable. Your case must be extremely rare if you cannot style your a-tag correctly without a clickable div.

Comment: In my case I have a tree where each node is a div with 100% width. When user clicks on that div the node is expanded/collaspsed except when he clicks directly on a text (a-tag). In that case the page is redirected to details of the particular item. Anyway the question is not about my html code. There can be other cases when you need to set window.location in an event fired by a middle click